# What is the difference between a ytd report and 12 mtd?

Tags: sas, business-logic

Whats the difference between 12 mtd , 12 mtd rolling and ytd calculation

Answer (score 9, accepted):

12 mtd goes back 12 months, whereas a ytd is from the first day of the current year (calendar, fiscal, whatever) to the current day.

Comment: To my mind, the "to-date" portion of mtd makes it rolling by definition.

Comment: I agree, not sure what the difference might be between 12mtd and 12mtd rolling.  One possibility is that a rolling average is what's being asked for in the latter case.

Answer (score 1):

Example:

Today=20090318

REPORT TYPE - REPORT PERIOD

---

12MTD report - 20080401 to 20090318

YTD report - 20090101 to 20090318

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [Hank Gay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4203/hank-gay)'s answer, a 12 mtd calculation is the same as a 12 mtd rolling calculation.

General, you would normally see a 3 mtd rolling, or 6 mtd rolling calcuations.